# Meaning to the homeless dog in Netflix’s Fractured

Tags: character, fractured

Was there any meaning/symbolism to the homeless dog that has contributed to the whole tragedy in the Netflix’s movie *Fractured* (2019)?

Comment: He was plot device, that's it I guess.